# How to convert char character to date in SAS (University)?

Tags: string, date, sas, type-conversion, format

This is a pretty simple question, already asked in several blogs. However, I'm trying all kinds of things and it's not working. Idk if this is happen because I'm using SAS University or if I'm doing something wrong when I input the values.

What I'm trying to do is to convert a column in string format to date format.

```
/*Dataset for practice*/
data test;
  input date_1 $ value_1;
  cards;
20151102 1000
20151010 500
;
run;

data test_new; 
  set test; 
  date_1_new = input(date_1,yymmdd10.);
format date_1_new yymmdd10.;
run;
```

The script above returns a missing value for date_1_new. What seems weird for me is that the code below, which uses a numeric value, simply convert the numeric to text and then to date. And it's working. It's the same principle, but it works.

```
/*Dataset for practice*/
data test;
  input date_1 value_1;
  cards;
20151102 1000
20151010 500
;
run;

data test_new; 
  set test; 
  date_1_new = input(put(date_1,8.),yymmdd10.);
format date_1_new yymmdd10.;
run;
```

Why is the first code not working? It looks like I'm doing the same thing...
Note: The same error occurs when using yymmdd8.

Comment: You can not input numbers. Convert to String 1st. `date_1_new = input(put(date_1, z8.),yymmdd10.);` Well, you can, but formatting does not compute.

Comment: @pinegulf just tried... it didn't work.
I am not inputting numbers. As you can see on the first part of my post, I am using a char variable (defined by the $). That's why I tried the input(date_1, yymmdd10.). In the second part of my post I show that I converted a numeric to string and used input(), and it did work. So for me it doesn't make sense that the first code doesnt work

Comment: Ooops. Yeah. Discard the prior comment.

Comment: I ran both your examples and they worked fine.   Try starting a new session!

Comment: They worked for me as well.  Are you getting any notes in the log that might give a clue?

Comment: Are you sure that is a space after the first variable and not a tab or other non-graphic character? I don't think the INPUT() function can handle strings in the form `YYYYMMDD<TAB>`.

Comment: @AllanBowe I tried this code at work (using SAS Guide) and it worked just fine. I think there's something about SAS University

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your input lines actually have spaces and not some other character(s) between the fields.  That could mess-up your original INPUT statement.

Also your INPUT() function is using width 10 on the informat, but your data is only 8 characters long.  So if there is some non digit, non space characters in characters 9 or 10 of your variable then the INPUT() function call will fail.